# Angular JS posting image and hidden field data to php

Tags: php, angularjs

I am facing a problem in accessing the value of hidden field.
I have made  an image cropping  application in which i am asking  the user to upload an image and a UI is provided to help the user to select the area to crop. Then the top left x and y coordinate and the width  and height  of the selected area is stored as a semicolon separated string in a hidden input field and when the 'Crop' button is clicked the image  and the hidden filed value is passed to the crop.php file. But the values of the hidden field is not accessible  in the php  file.

My html file which provides browse  and crop functionality -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        
              Crop

        </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
  
    <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
     rel = "stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />

    <script>
    
    var app =  angular.module('main-App',[]);
    app.controller('AdminController', function($scope, $http) {
        
        $scope.form = [];
        $scope.files = [];
        $scope.progressBar=0;
        $scope.progressCounter=0;
        
        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert('Sub');
            $scope.form.image = $scope.files[0];
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'crop.php',
                processData: false,
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("image", $scope.form.image);  
                    return formData;  
                },  

                data : $scope.form,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },

                uploadEventHandlers: {
                    progress: function (e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            $scope.progressBar = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                            $scope.progressCounter = $scope.progressBar;
                            $("#completion").css("width", $scope.progressBar+'%');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    alert($scope.form.params);
             });
            

        };
        $scope.uploadedFile = function(element) {
            $scope.currentFile = element.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $scope.image_source = event.target.result
                $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                $scope.files = element.files;
                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
            $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
                onSelectStart: {enable:true},
                onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                    document.getElementById("params").value=selection.x1+';'+selection.y1+';'+selection.width+';'+selection.height;
                    alert(document.getElementById("params").value);
                }
            });
            
                
        }
    });

</script>

<style>
    
    html,body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper{
        height:auto;
    }
    .wrapper img {
        
        height:100%;
        color:grey;
        text-align: center;
        line-height:100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }

    
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="main-App" ng-controller="AdminController">
    <form ng-submit="submit()" name="form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row flex-items-xs-center">
                    <div class="col-md-9">

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                        <img id="photo" name="photo" src="{{image_source}}"  alt="Image preview..." class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="border-style:dashed">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary">

                                        <input ng-model="form.image" type="file" class="form-control input-lg" name="image" id="image" 
                                        accept = "image/*"
                                        onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this)"
                                        style="display:none;" >

                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;
                                        Browse

                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;"/>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>&nbsp;
                                        Crop
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="params" id="params" value="0;0;0;0" ng-model="params" />         
    </form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" id ="completion" name="completion"
                    aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="50" style="width:0%;height:10px;border-width:0px;border-radius:2px;">
                    </div> 
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

the UI -
[image]

crop.php -

```
<?php


$uncropped_path = '/var/www/html/images/original/';
$cropped_path = '/var/www/html/images/cropped/';



if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    //$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $uncropped_path.$image);

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    print_r($data);
    

}else{

    echo "Image Is Empty";

}

function doResize($filename,$size,$resize_path)
{
    $image = new Imagick();
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    $image->readImageBlob($file);
    $dimensions = $image->getImageGeometry(); 
    
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($filename);  
    $name = $pathInfo['filename'];
    

    $srcWidth =  $dimensions['width'];
    $srcHeight =  $dimensions['height']; 
    
    list($resWidth,$resHeight) = getResizeDim($size,$srcWidth,$srcHeight);
    
    $image->resizeImage($resWidth,$resHeight,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,.85);
    
    $image->writeImage($resize_path);

        
}



function getResizeDim($size,$srcWidth,$srcHeight)
{
    $width;
    $height;

    if($srcHeight > $srcWidth)
    {
        if($srcHeight > $size)
            $height = $size;
        else $height = $srcHeight;

        $width = ceil($height*($srcWidth/$srcHeight));
    }
    else {

        if($srcWidth > $size)
            $width = $size;
        else $width = $srcWidth;

        $height = ceil($width*($srcHeight/$srcWidth));
    }
    return array($width,$height);
}
```

When i try to print the data received  in php  i get the following -

[image]

Moreover the data array in the php seems to be empty.
I have read various similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them worked in my case.